# How to call method by Name from variable value in perl?

Tags: perl

I have name of method which I have to call (from another script btw) from arguments - as a variable.
In a big simplify:

```
$method1 = "hello()";
```

And I have to write:

```
hello();
```

but I don't know what name is in #method1.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not really recommended because there are safety issues, but you can use the name of a subroutine to call it:

```perl
my $method = "hello";
{
  no strict 'refs';
  &{$method}();  # same as hello()
}
```

This `&{...}()` syntax “dereferences” the subroutine name and calls it.

If you're calling methods on an object, you can skip the `no strict 'refs'` part:

```perl
my $method = 'name';
$object->$method();  # same as $object->name
```

If you only want to allow a couple of subroutines, it would be much better to store them in a hash table:

```perl
my %known_functions = (
  hello => \&hello,  # \& stores a reference to a subroutine 
  bye => \&not_hello,  # added benefit: renaming them
);

# define the functions somewhere
sub hello { ... }
sub not_hello { ... }

# can't access secret methods unless they are added to the hash table
sub secret { ... }

# use a hash lookup and call the method
my $method = 'hello';
$known_functions{$method}();
```

Comment: Thank you, it works for me.
A very valuable answer!